# Mass insert on Cassandra from Spark with different TTL

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, ttl

I want to insert huge volume of data from Spark into Cassandra.  The data has a timestamp column which determines ttl.  But, this differs for each row.  My question is, how can I handle ttl while inserting data in bulk from Spark.

My current implementation -

```
    raw_data_final.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
       .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).options(Map("table" -> offerTable ,
       "keyspace" -> keySpace, "spark.cassandra.output.ttl" -> ttl_seconds)).save
```

Here raw_data_final has around a million records with each record yielding a different ttl.  So, is there a way to do a bulk insert and somehow specify ttl from a column within raw_data.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain more? How you are going to use timestamp column as ttl?

Comment: There is an expr_dt column, from which I can calculate ttl. (ttl = expr_dt - current timestamp).  So, I can have ttl as one of my input columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supported by setting the `WriteConf` parameter with `TTLOption.perRow` option.  The [official documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#using-a-different-value-for-each-row) has following example for RDDs:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.writer._
...
rdd.saveToCassandra("test", "tab", writeConf = WriteConf(ttl = TTLOption.perRow("ttl")))
```

In your case you need to replace `"ttl"` with the name of your column with TTL.

I'm not sure that you can set this directly on DataFrame, but you can always get RDD from DataFrame, and use `saveToCassandra` with `WriteConf`...

Update in September 2020th: support for writetime and ttl in dataframes was added in the [Spark Cassandra Connector 2.5.0](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all)

Comment: Do we have an equivalent code in Java?  I tried searching but I see only scala way to do this.

Comment: No, but it should be straightforward to translate

Comment: how can I add the cassandra connection config as part of this conf? Thanks

Comment: cassandra connection config is defined in another place, when you create spark context, for example